# emacs comment indentation Qt style

Tags: c++, emacs, coding-style, comments, indentation

I am in C++ mode in emacs, creating block comments for Doxygen in the Qt style.  The following is expected behavior:

```
/*!
 * comment
 */
```

Using "tab" on each line indents this in an expected way.

However, the style in this large codebase is to use large "flags" of asterisks to create an open box, like this:

```
/*!
 ***************************
 * Comment
 ***************************
 */
```

This is imposed on me, I cannot change it.

When I get to the 2nd asterisk in the 2nd line, I get this:

```
/*!
**
```

rather than this

```
/*!
 **
```

The asterisks "jump back" a column, and now everything is justified left, rather than aligning under the first asterisk.

How can I change this behavior?  The 2nd asterisk seems to invoke unique behavior this way, any other character entered there does not "push back" the previously entered asterisk.

I cannot just use a template to do this, because the code layout must be invariant under an indent-region over the whole file.

Comment: There are a myriad of ways to influence the emacs comment and other style.  See here as a starting point: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Style-Variables.html#Style-Variables

Comment: I know, and you could spend hours by trial and error looking for what setting might affect this.  In fact, I already did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can influence this with comment line up functions.  See here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Comment-Line_002dUp.html#Comment-Line_002dUp

Comment: Perfect.  This was not easily user configurable, but by modifying the logic of c-lineup-C-comments I was able to get the behavior I needed.  I would upvote you but I just signed up and don't have any rep yet.  In particular, this behavior related to the difference between the "starterlen" (length of the comment start sequence on prior line) and the "prefixlen" which is the comment prefix on the current line.  The behavior changed from alignment to justification based on a comparison of those two lengths.